GStreamer audio source to RTSP audio & video
I am trying to take an audio source and create an RTSP stream that includes both the audio and a visualization of the audio. The following is the command I am trying.
gst-launch-1.0 \
      rtspclientsink name=s location=rtsp://localhost:8554/music \
      alsasrc device=plughw:CARD=Device,DEV=0 ! tee name=t ! queue ! audioconvert ! avenc_aac ! s. \
      t. ! queue ! wavescope ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! s.

When I work with just the audio, it works fine. When I work with just the audio visualization, it works, but the resulting video is not very good and very choppy. But then whey I try both, it does not work at all, it just seems to hang. Any suggestions on what I am missing?
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://localhost:8554/music
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Prerolled, waiting for progress to finish...
Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
Progress: (open) Opened Stream
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstAudioSrcClock
Redistribute latency...
Progress: (request) Sending RECORD request
Redistribute latency...


I made two changes and it is working now. I changed from using avenc_acc to using voaacenc, and I swapped the order of the audio and video streams. I still need to make some adjustments because of dropped samples, but at least it's working. Here is the modified pipeline:
gst-launch-1.0 \
    rtspclientsink name=s location=rtsp://localhost:8554/music \
    alsasrc device=plughw:CARD=Device,DEV=0 ! tee name=t ! queue ! audioconvert ! wavescope ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! s. \
    t. ! queue ! audioconvert ! voaacenc ! s.

